# Uploading file to Sand boxed Page

Tags: c#, sharepoint, webclient

I have sand boxed solution running in my site collection.
I have uploaded a file as byte array to sand boxed solution and on sand boxed solution that byte array is convert to file and save in a document library. I used

```
webclient.UploadData(address, method, byte[])
```

I can get byte array send to sand boxed page through Page.Request.InStream 
But when I try to send byte[] of file sized 50 MB then in sand boxed page, I am unable to get that byte array.

How can I send byte array to sand boxed page and procces that byte[] in sand boxed i.e adding it as a file in Document library??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this topic will help you

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/tfsadmin/thread/b3cee101-1f6f-4c1c-a28d-71b393063894

> By default SharePoint allows a maximum file size of 50MB that can be
>   uploaded

Comment: I am not allow to access central admin because I am uploading it Office 365.